# Reuse execution plan for query against view with different WHERE clauses

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

I have (for slightly weird reasons) ended up with a view which takes ~30 seconds to compile, but < 3 seconds to run.

It's a view sitting at the top of a huge stack of nested views, each with many layers of sequential CTEs. The underlying dataset isn't all that large, which I imagine is why the query ultimately runs pretty quickly.

If we were always reading the whole table, that would be fine - the first query woudl be slow and every later hit would be fine.
Unfortunately, the accessing code is going to want to read it with a date window.

`SELECT * FROM myView WHERE date BETWEEN 'foo' AND 'bar'`

The first time you run that, it takes 30 seconds to compile an Exec Plan; the second time is runs in 1-3 seconds.

Is there anyway to prevent that recompilation?
I recognise that it may result it the final execution plan not being so efficient, because it's optimised for a different clause, but the data is pretty uniform so I wouldn't expect it to be TOO bad, and the 30 second compilation time is way too painful.

---

I've looked through pages like [these](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) [pages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/). But not much of it immediately jumped out as relevant to me, and bits that did didn't seem to achieve my goal (though I could easily have missed something)

---

**EDIT:**

`STATISTICS TIME ON` output for a similar view that takes ~ 6 to run when cold, or about 1/2 a second to run when pre-compiled (in fact, specifically, it's from one of the views a layer down in the nesting.)

```
SELECT * FROM myView WHERE date_incurred < '2017-02-20'

Run with param = '2017-02-20'

SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 5008 ms, elapsed time = 5184 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
(77 row(s) affected)
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 452 ms,  elapsed time = 772 ms.

Run with param = '2017-02-20'

SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
(77 row(s) affected)
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 437 ms,  elapsed time = 582 ms.

Run with param = '2017-02-21'

SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 4618 ms, elapsed time = 4877 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
(79 row(s) affected)
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 359 ms,  elapsed time = 643 ms.

Run with param = '2017-02-21'

SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
(79 row(s) affected)
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 483 ms,  elapsed time = 559 ms.
```

Comment: Nesting queries like this is performance timebomb. Take a look here about the horrors of nesting views. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: how are your estimating compile time.Can you paste output of `set statistics time on` for different cases

Comment: So I was estimating it based on the execution time of the query in a window, it's pretty easy to judge the difference when it's so severe :) Will provide STATS data.

Comment: "Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this… Doctor: Then stop doing it…". It seems to me that your problem here is not how to better cache execution plans, but how to avoid creating a schema so byzantine that it takes SQLS 30 seconds to compute an execution plan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer (IMO): `sp_executesql`/`sp_execute`

```
DECLARE @query int;  
EXEC sp_executesql
    N'SELECT * FROM vlpl_combined_costs_with_invoices WHERE date_incurred < @dateParam OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)',
    N'@dateParam datetime',
    '2017-09-10'


EXEC sp_prepare @query output,   
    N'@dateParam datetime',  
    N'SELECT * FROM myView WHERE date < @dateParam OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)';
EXEC sp_execute @query, '2017-09-07'
EXEC sp_unprepare @query;
```

I believe the former (`sp_executesql`) to be considered better, though I don't know specifically why.

---

**Explanation**:

When the execution plan of a **stored procedure** is generated, it is generated based on the parameters passed at the time and then the same plan is reused for subsequent executions of the same stored procedure regardless of the parameter values – just the name has to match[1].

When an **ad hoc SQL batch** (i.e. a regular hard coded `SELECT`) is run, its execution plan is also stored, but in order to be used the text of the query has to exactly match (whitespace AND casing AND parameter values included).

**sp_execute** allows the query plan of an ad hoc query to be stored independent of the parameter values so that it can be reused across different sets of parameters (I think the rest of the text still has to be identical though). i.e. it’s designed for the exact use-case I’ve got here.

(Credit for idea and explanation goes to Andy Thomas as Softwire)

[1] and some other stuff I believe, but that’s not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer: non-inline function

Exec Plan caching will use the param as first invoked, and then continue to use that plan thereafter.

Downsides
 - extremely verbose to define a function to wrap a view :(
 - would need a separate function for each different "type" of query against the view (or a complex function with lots of parameters, many of which are NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer: using a sproc

Again you get Exec Plan caching.
This time you don't have to do the verbose table definition as for the inline table-valued function, but retrieving the output from the Sproc doesn't necessarily work as well as it would for a SELECT or a FUNCTION.